# Converting Pandas Series to a String to Convert DateTime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a DataFrame that includes column `df['date'] and df['time']`

Which I have put together in one column named `df['datetime']`

the output looks like the following: `2017-04-12 17:30:18.733`

My end goal is to have it converted to a string  `Wed, 12 Apr 2017 17:30:18 733`

When I try different methods as `pd.to_datetime()` it tells me I need it to be a string.

and I can't find a method to turn the whole column to a bunch of strings

I tried calling `.astype(str)` `.apply(str)`

Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you please post your code?

Comment: try out `.apply(pd.to_datetime).apply(<strftime to convert back to string in your format>)` to the datetime series

Comment: `df[['date', 'time', 'datetime']].info()`?  What types are your columns?

Comment: date - object
time - object
datetime - datetime64

Comment: @AnandSKumar Tried what you wrote, and it still wants a str not a timestamp

Comment: @Bit This is literally my code.. 
The import of the data is from A CSV File

Comment: ok so you already have datetime, just use `.apply(datetime.datetime.strftime)` to convert it to the format you want

Answer (score 1):

You are taking to strings (one in the `date` column and the other in the `time` column), joining them together with a space to create a new datetime string (e.g. `"2017-04-12 17:30:18.733"`).  You then use `strptime` to parse this string into a datetime object.  I used a form that is amenable to the inclusion of microseconds or not.  You now use 'strftime' to parse this datetime object back into your desired string format.

```
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2017-04-12', '2017-04-13'], 
                   'time': ['17:30:18.733', '07:30:18']})


def date_parser(date_string):
    try:
        timestamp = datetime.strptime(date_string, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
        timestamp = timestamp.strftime('%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %f')[:-3]
    except ValueError:
        timestamp = datetime.strptime(date_string, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        timestamp = timestamp.strftime('%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S 000')
    return timestamp

df['datetime_str'] = (df['date'] + ' ' + df['time']).apply(lambda x: date_parser(x))

>>> df
         date          time                   datetime_str
0  2017-04-12  17:30:18.733  Wed, 12 Apr 2017 17:30:18 733
1  2017-04-13      07:30:18  Thu, 13 Apr 2017 07:30:18 000
```

Comment: When I run it it says that "ValueError" time data '2017-04-12' does not match the format '%Y-%m-$d %H:%M:%S'

Comment: wait there is progress.. 
Will update! Thank you thus far!!

Comment: I converted df['date'] and df['time'] to a date time object and now the Error I get is Incompatible type [<U1] For a datetime / time delta operation

any idea where to head from here?

Answer (score 0):

use something like this:

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.datetime.strftime('%D %d ...the format you want...'))
```